# Savagery (Countable or Uncountable)

Tags: grammar, word-usage, articles

According to the dictionary definitions, the word "[Savagary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/savagery)" can be either a countable or an uncountable noun.
I was wondering if using the article "an" is superfluous in the following example:

> What terrorists do is **an** absolute savagery.

Comment: Your dictionary definition indicates that the countable use is for individual acts of savagery. "What terrorists do" (note spelling) does not refer to 'an individual act'.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kate Bunting for pointing out my typo. I edited the thread. According to your confirmation and as I had realized, the indefinite article "an" is a mistake and must be removed. Thank you again.

Comment: All the references to [***is a savagery***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+a+savagery%22) that I've just looked at in Google Books seem to be references to an ***attribute***, not an ***act***. And terrorists do / commit ***acts*** of terrorism, not ***attributes***.

Comment: So "an" is redundant @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica right?

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+savagery%2Cis+a+savagery&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20savagery%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20savagery%3B%2Cc0), showing that most people *don't* include the article in such contexts.

Comment: It's savag**ery**. This is the kind of word that is just not used in the plural.

Answer (score -1):

Both of the following sentences sound fairly aristocratic to my ear.

However, I have seen contemporary English writing which uses both sentence-structures.

- What terrorists do is **an** absolute savagery.
- What terrorists do is absolute savagery.

### Examples of the Pattern "*[verb] an absolute*"

#### Example One of "*[verb] an absolute*"

> Paraphrased Quote: "The progress the Trump administration has made ***is an absolute*** evisceration of law." - Jefferson Sessions (Former Attorney General of the United States)
>
> - Title: Jeff Sessions: Biden administration border policy 'an absolute evisceration of law'
> - Author of News Article: Jeff Poor
> - Date of Publication: 09.23.22

#### Example Two of "*[verb] an absolute*"

> "Joya’s Cafe ***Is An Absolute*** Must Try For Anyone That Enjoys Great Food"
>
> Author: Chelsea Wiley
>
> Date: September 2022

#### Example Three of "*[verb] an absolute*"

> The appraisal process is an absolute joke

#### Example Four of "*[verb] an absolute*"

> This movie is an absolute gem.

#### Example Five of "***[verb] an absolute***"

> Bob's car ***looks like an absolute*** work of art.

#### Example Six of "***[verb] an absolute***"###

> Bob's car ***looks like an absolute*** work of art.

## One Final Note

I would like to provide some examples of sentences which use the phrase "*is absolute*" instead of "is ***an*** absolute". However, the coffee shop I am using internet at is closing.